# Downloading file over https using WebClient

Tags: .net, https, ftp

I am currently trying to download a file over https using System.Net.WebClient

The file gets created locally, but when I open it, it just has the text 'Virtual user xxxxxx logged in.'  where xxxxxx is the username that was sent in.

I have been trying to get this working for a while with the same results.  I wanted to find out if anyone else ever had this issue, and if so, were you able to move past it?

Here is the code where I try to do the download.

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    Dim webConnection As New WebClient()
    Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "password")

    Try
        webConnection.BaseAddress = "https://ftp.sitename.com/content/"
        webConnection.Credentials = credentials
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        webConnection.DownloadFile("https://ftp.sitename.com/content/source_file.dat", "destination_file.dat")
        MsgBox("File Downloaded!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `DownloadFile` has to be the full URL of the file you want to download. Here it looks like you're passing a directory. If you want to download the file "file_name.dat" and save it to the current working directory as "file_name.dat", you would write:

```
webConnection.DownloadFile("https://ftp.sitename.com/content/file_name.dat", "file_name.dat")
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally omitted that when I was taking out the actual file names.  I edited my example above.  Thanks for pointing that out.  The issue still stands.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case for "https : //"-download (I'm new in WebClient & Co., so some parts of the code might be redundant, or fit to this scenario only...), 
I needed the bitmap as object, so saving the stream is not implemented here:

```
    Public Shared Function GetImage(url As string) As Bitmap

    Dim x As Bitmap = Nothing
    Try
        Dim urlpath = $"{url}"
        Dim cred = $"user:password"
        Dim req = WebRequest.Create(urlpath)
        req.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cred))
        req.ContentType = "application/json"
        Dim wr As WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Dim recstr = wr.GetResponseStream
        x = New Bitmap(recstr)
    Catch ex As WebException
    End Try
    Return x
End Function
```